# Drawing text on reversed Y Axis

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi+

I am writing an visualizer application: it load building geometry from XML and draw it on the screen.
Building consists from rectangular rooms, many of them - so i want to draw their names on them.

I use [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140810175854/http://bobpowell.net/ReverseAxisText.aspx) tutorial to flip Y axis in my form, because building data stored in Cartesian coordinates. And convert all of them to classic Windows "y grows down" system while drawing looks like weird.

Also i need to scale and translate my "scene" to the bottom left corner.
And, the last of my pain, i need to flip my text again - because it will flip too!

As [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140810175854/http://bobpowell.net/ReverseAxisText.aspx) say, i need to:

1. Flip Y axis, scale and move scene to desired positions
2. Draw building geometry (just rectangles) in Cartesian coordinates
3. Return to "Y grows down" system, scale and move again
4. Draw text in this "classic" system

But coordinates of text are invalid!
They are moved down from the correct position :( 

So this is my question - how to calculate new text coordinates in Windows Forms object *correctly*.

```
void VisualizerForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Setup graphics output settings
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    
    // Move coordinate system center to the bottom left corner,
    // scale it to user-defined scale value and flip Y axis (mul it scale to -1)
    g.ScaleTransform(m_scale, -m_scale, MatrixOrder.Append);
    g.TranslateTransform(50, Height - 50, MatrixOrder.Append);
    
    // ... Draw some complex building geometry ...
    
    // Draw building room
    var customPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0f / g.DpiX);
    var rect = new RectangleF(box.X1, box.Y1, (box.X2 - box.X1), (box.Y2 - box.Y1));
    g.DrawRectangle(customPen, box.X1, box.Y1, (box.X2 - box.X1), (box.Y2 - box.Y1));

    GraphicsState gs = g.Save();
    
    // First reset transform matrix
    g.ResetTransform();
    // Then again scale and move scene, but now with classic down-incresed Y axis
    g.ScaleTransform(m_scale, m_scale, MatrixOrder.Append);
    g.TranslateTransform(50, Height - 50, MatrixOrder.Append);
    
    // All Y coords now must be inverted :/ *sigh*
    box.Y1 *= -1.0f;
    box.Y2 *= -1.0f;
    rect = new RectangleF(box.X1, box.Y1, Math.Abs(box.X2 - box.X1), Math.Abs(box.Y2 - box.Y1));

    // FIXME: This text is drawing in incorrect place
    var fnt = new Font("Arial", 40f / g.DpiX, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    g.DrawString("ID: " + box.Id, fnt, Brushes.Black, rect, stringFormat);

    g.Restore(gs);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got it!
The class below draw rectangle with specified text in its center - inside Y-reversed scene.
Text scale automatically to fit actual rectangle size. Enjoy :)

```
class RectangleWithText
{
    RectangleF m_extent = new RectangleF();
    string m_text = "";

    Font m_textFont = null;
    RectangleF m_textRect = new RectangleF();

    public RectangleWithText( RectangleF extent, string text )
    {
        m_extent = extent;
        m_text = text;
    }

    public void Draw( Graphics g )
    {
        var dashedGrayPen = new Pen( Color.Gray, 1.0f / g.DpiX ) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash };
        var brownPen = new Pen( Color.Brown, 1.0f / g.DpiX );

        // Draw rectangle itself
        g.DrawRectangle( brownPen, m_extent.X, m_extent.Y, m_extent.Width, m_extent.Height );

        // Draw text on it
        var extentCenter = new PointF( ( m_extent.Left + m_extent.Right ) / 2, ( m_extent.Bottom + m_extent.Top ) / 2 );
        DrawText( g, m_text, extentCenter, m_extent );

        }
    }

    private void DrawText( Graphics g, string text, PointF ptStart, RectangleF extent )
    {
        var gs = g.Save();

        // Inverse Y axis again - now it grow down;
        // if we don't do this, text will be drawn inverted
        g.ScaleTransform( 1.0f, -1.0f, MatrixOrder.Prepend );

        if ( m_textFont == null )
        {
            // Find the maximum appropriate text size to fix the extent
            float fontSize = 100.0f;
            Font fnt;
            SizeF textSize;
            do
            {
                fnt = new Font( "Arial", fontSize / g.DpiX, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
                textSize = g.MeasureString( text, fnt );
                m_textRect = new RectangleF( new PointF( ptStart.X - textSize.Width / 2.0f, -ptStart.Y - textSize.Height / 2.0f ), textSize );

                var textRectInv = new RectangleF( m_textRect.X, -m_textRect.Y, m_textRect.Width, m_textRect.Height );
                if ( extent.Contains( textRectInv ) )
                    break;

                fontSize -= 1.0f;
                if ( fontSize <= 0 )
                {
                    fontSize = 1.0f;
                    break;
                }
            } while ( true );

            m_textFont = fnt;
        }

        // Create a StringFormat object with the each line of text, and the block of text centered on the page
        var stringFormat = new StringFormat()
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        };
        g.DrawString( text, m_textFont, Brushes.Black, m_textRect, stringFormat );

        g.Restore( gs );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
void DrawDigonalString(Graphics G, string S, Font F, Brush B, PointF P, int Angle)
{
    SizeF MySize = G.MeasureString(S, F);
    G.TranslateTransform(P.X + MySize.Width / 2, P.Y + MySize.Height / 2);
    G.RotateTransform(Angle);
    G.DrawString(S, F, B, new PointF(-MySize.Width / 2, -MySize.Height / 2));
    G.RotateTransform(-Angle);
    G.TranslateTransform(-P.X - MySize.Width / 2, -P.Y- MySize.Height / 2);
}
```

Comment: With agjusted translation (`g.TranslateTransform(50, Height - 100, MatrixOrder.Append)` you function work nice, thanks. I call it in this way: `DrawDigonalString(g, "ID: " + box.Id, fnt, Brushes.Black, new PointF(box.X1, -box.Y1), 0)`.
P.S. Can you briefly explain how it works?

Comment: I found only one problem: text and rectangles are scaled in different ways. I.e. with small scale values text "dart out" from it's parent rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this thread when I wanted to do exactly the same thing as the OP.  It was frustrating to try and piece everything together, especially since the above example which divides the font size by the DPI a bit artificial especially on newer screens with higher DPI.

So, I worked up my own example, which I have pasted below.  To use this example, create a Windows Forms app and generate handlers for 'ResizeEnd' and 'Paint' (the 'ResizeEnd'handler isn't really necessary but it is a convenient way to re-run the program by slightly resizing the Form1 window).  Then Replace the contents of the Paint and resize handlers with the code below, and also copy paste the two helper functions 'ConvertRectangleToPointFArray()' and 'TextInsideRectangle()' into your project.  As written, the example program will draw a coordinate system near the bottom of the form, and label the "X" and "Y" axes correctly (which requires that the 'Y' string be inverted before it gets drawn.  If the 'verbose' bool variable is set to 'true', some diagnostic information will get written to the Output window.  Enjoy!

================= Pasted Code ===========================

```
  private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    //Step1: Change from Y-down to Y-up increasing using
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter; //  04/02/23 Changed Page units from pix to mm

    g.ScaleTransform(1.0f, -1.0f);//flip y
    Rectangle clientrect = this.ClientRectangle; //this is in pixels, NOT mm!

    PointF[] rectpoints = {new PointF(clientrect.X, clientrect.Y),new PointF(clientrect.X, clientrect.Bottom)};

    PointF[] ptf2 = { new PointF(clientrect.X, clientrect.Bottom) }; //have to have an array to use g.TransformPoints()
    g.TransformPoints(CoordinateSpace.Page, CoordinateSpace.Device, ptf2);

    g.TranslateTransform(ptf2[0].X, -ptf2[0].Y); //move origin to bottom-left corner
    g.TranslateTransform(20, 20);//move origin to right 20 and up 20 mm

    //Step2: draw coordinate system lines in new coordinate system
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), 0, 0, 100, 0);
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), 0, 0, 0, 100);

    //Step3: Save the transforms with g.Save()
    GraphicsState transState = g.Save(); //do this so can restore later

    //"Y" string.
    Rectangle Yrect = new Rectangle(-5,100, 10, 10); //this is in mm with origin at (20,20)mm from bottom left-hand corner of window
    StringFormat YdrawFormat = new StringFormat();
    YdrawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    YdrawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    //"X" string.
    Rectangle Xrect = new Rectangle(100,-5, 10, 10); //this is in mm with origin at (20,20)mm from bottom left-hand corner of window
    StringFormat XdrawFormat = new StringFormat();
    XdrawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    XdrawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    //now draw desired text
    //bool IsVerbose = true;
    bool IsVerbose = false;
    TextInsideRectangle(e, Yrect, "Y", YdrawFormat, IsVerbose);
    TextInsideRectangle(e, Xrect, "X", XdrawFormat, IsVerbose);
  }
  private void TextInsideRectangle(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rect, string text, StringFormat fmt, bool verbose)
  {
    //Purpose:  Place and size the given text inside the given rectangle
    //Inputs:
    //  PaintEventArgs e assumed to be set for y-up, origin at bottom left, mm scaling
    //  ptf = 2-element PointF array containing (rect.X, rect.Y), (rect.Width, rect.Height) in desired coord sys
    //  rect = Rectangle object in (x,y, width,height) format
    //  text = string object containing text to be displayed
    //Procedure:
    //  Step1: Save the current transform
    //  Step2: draw the given rectangle onto the Form surface (DEBUG only)
    //  Step3: Flip y axis so text is drawn correctly
    //  Step3: Draw the given text, centered in the given rectangle
    //  Step4: Iteratively modify the font size such that the given text fits inside the given rectangle
    //  Step5: Refresh the screen and redraw

    //Step1: Save the current transform
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    GraphicsState transState = g.Save(); //do this so can restore later

    //Step2: draw the given rectangle onto the Form surface (for debug only)
    if (verbose)
    {
        RectangleF mm_tgt_rect = rect;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkCyan), Rectangle.Round(mm_tgt_rect));
    }

    //Step3: Flip y axis so text is drawn correctly
    g.ScaleTransform(1.0f, -1.0f, MatrixOrder.Prepend); //origin still at bottom left of screen

    //Step3: Draw the given text, centered in the given rectangle
    PointF rect_ctr = new PointF((rect.X + rect.Width/2), -rect.Y - rect.Height/2);

    // Create font and brush.
    int fontsize = 1;
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", fontsize);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    //Step4: Iteratively modify the font size such that the given text fits inside the given rectangle
    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, drawFont);

    if (verbose)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("text size is {0} x {1}, enclosing rect size is {2}, {3} ",
          textSize.Width, textSize.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }

    while (textSize.Width <= rect.Width && textSize.Height <= rect.Height)
    {
        if (verbose)
        {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("text size of {0} x {1} is smaller than rect", textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
        }
        fontsize++;
        drawFont = new Font("Arial", fontsize);
        textSize = g.MeasureString(text, drawFont);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFont, drawBrush, rect_ctr.X, rect_ctr.Y, fmt);//this is the 'inverted/reversed' text
    }

    if (verbose)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("text size of {0} x {1} is smaller than rect", textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("final text size = {0} x {1}: enclosing rect size is {2}, {3}",
          textSize.Width, textSize.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }

    //Step5: Refresh the screen and redraw
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, drawFont, drawBrush, rect_ctr.X, rect_ctr.Y, fmt);
  }
  private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Invalidate();
  }
  private PointF[] ConvertRectangleToPointFArray(RectangleF rectF)
  {
    //Purpose: convert a Rectangle or RectangleF object into a 2-element array of PointF objects
    //Inputs:
    //  rectF = Rectangle or RectangleF object
    //Outputs:
    //  returns a 2-element array of PointF objects
    //  points[0] = PointF(rectF.X, rectF.Y)
    //  points[1] = PointF(rectF.Width,rectF.Height)

    PointF[] points = new PointF[2];
    points[0] = new PointF(rectF.X, rectF.Y);
    points[1] = new PointF(rectF.Width,rectF.Height);

    return points;
  }
```